# If X~beta($\theta$,1) then Z=-ln(x) ~exp(1/$\theta$)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I keep getting this,

$P(Z\leq z)=P(-ln(X) \leq z) = P(X \leq e^{-z}) = \int_{0}^{e^{-z}} \theta t^{\theta-1}dt = t^{\theta}|_{0}^{e^{-z}}=e^{-z\theta}$

$\frac{d}{dz}[e^{-z\theta}]=-\theta e^{-z\theta}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, but not quite:

$$P(Z\leq z)=P(-\ln (X) \leq z)=P(\ln(X)\color{red}{\geq}-z).$$

and it seems that you know how to take it from there, based on your earlier working.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake......... thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If I had a penny for every similar mistake that I had made...

Answer (score 0):

Very close,

here it is:
$$ 
 Pr(Z<z) = Pr(-ln(X)<z) = Pr(X>e^{-z}) = 1 - F_X(e^{-z})
$$
so,
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac d {dz} (1 - F_X(e^{-z})) =  (-e^{-z})(-f_X(e^{-z})) = e^{-z} \cdot \theta e^{-z(1-\theta)} = \theta e^{-z\theta}
$$